# Понимание версий AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Недавно начал работу над новым проектом и решил использовать AngularJS. До этого несколько раз откладывал его изучение.

Правильно ли я понял, что версии 1.х.х более пригодны для быстрого старта, а различия между версиями 1-2-4 не столь велики?

Я объясню почему сложилось такое впечатление, в первой версии есть файл angular.min.js, его подключаем и можно работать. Удобно, если проект на каком-то фреймворке на php(yii2, например). Второй и четвертый уже так не поставить. Нужен хипстерский набор утилит: отдельный вебсервер под node.js, npm, webpack и куча другого ненужного мусора(в моем случае). Я понимаю, современный веб, rest api и все дела, но это сейчас не использует ни одна веб-студия **среднего уровня**, всё ещё по старинке.

Почему не предусмотрели такую же компиляцию в 1 файл для удобной работы с вебсервером на PHP, например?

Comment: Различия между 1-4 версиями довольно значительны. Это почти как изучать два различных фреймворка. На каком вебсервере разрабатывать значения нет. Отдельный набор утилит angular 4 нужен только для разработки, в продакшене можете использовать, что хотите, потому что все компилируется в пару файлов. Используйте сразу angular 4.

Comment: Где взять 1 файл angular.min.js под 4ю версию? я вижу только установки под cli...

Comment: Как я написал выше, вам надо разрабатывать используя весь инструментарий. Потом все это компилируется в несколько файлов. И используется в продакшене по принципу *есть файл angular.min.js, его подключаем и можно работать*

Comment: Я не хочу ничего компилировать или использовать консоль. Мне это не нужно. Я хочу положить в папочку файл angular.min.js, а в своих других файлах вести уже разработку. Потом сжать всё в один/несколько файлов min и выкатить в продакшен.

Comment: Нет, это старый путь(шутка). Современный веб так не работает)) У вас так не получится с `angular 2/4`. Только с `angularJs` так можно сделать. Но я вам советую потратить N количество часов на ознакомление с `angular-cli`. Вам понравится!

Comment: Я пытался разобраться, но я не понимаю как мне совместить это с текущими проектами на PHP. В инструкции к установке на офф. сайте в самом начале "Install Node.js® and npm if they are not already on your machine.". Это отвратительно. Ну нет никакого желания юзать Node.js и держать 2 сервера. Один для фронтенда, другой для бэкэнда. Я понимаю, что это современный веб и в какой-то степени удобно, наверное, но для меня всё ещё это очень странно и дико. И ещё ведь сколько часов будет потрачено для написание REST API для взаимодействия сервера с клиентом...жуть. Эх, придётся использовать 1-ю версию)

Comment: Я повторю еще раз. Node.js нужен **только для разработки**. Никто немешает вам использовать ваш сервер на *php*!